# Geoloc is incorrect after update parts document in Solr

Tags: solr, coordinate

I want to update a particular field of a document in Solr. But after updating , the field `*_coordinate` was converted from `tdouble` to `array`. How can I fix it ? I use Apache Solr version 6.2.1.

This is my `dynamicField` in the schema file:

```
    <!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true" useDocValuesAsStored="false" />
```

This is the code that I used for update a field:

```
String solrID = (String) currentDoc.getFieldValue("id");
SolrInputDocument solrDocToIndex = new SolrInputDocument(); 
solrDocToIndex.addField("id", solrID);
Map<String, String> partialUpdate = new HashMap<>();
partialUpdate.put("add", "Solr Demo");
solrDocToIndex.addField("tags", partialUpdate);
```

I have a field `geoloc_0_coordinate`. Before do update it has value `12.123456`. But after running the code update, it changed to `[12.123456,12.123456]`